# How to make the libvirt VM installed under the regular user boot during the system bootup?

Tags: libvirt, virsh

I installed a virtual machine under a regular user(in other words, not under `root` user) with `virt-install` and configured this VM to boot automatically:

```
$ virsh dominfo vm
Id:             1
Name:           vm
UUID:           eef95dd6-5efe-4059-8dcc-3e35db12f55d
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         4
CPU time:       253.7s
Max memory:     4194304 KiB
Used memory:    4194304 KiB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      enable
Managed save:   no
Security model: none
Security DOI:   0

$ ls -l /home/user/.config/libvirt/qemu/autostart/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 47 Apr 30 16:59 vm.xml -> /home/user/.config/libvirt/qemu/vm.xml
$
```

The `vm` indeed starts automatically, but only when the regular user has logged in. How to make the `vm` boot already during the system bootup when the regular user has not yet logged in? I also made a symlink under `/etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart/`, but this did not help.

Answer (score 1):

To have something running at boot you need to configure a systemd unit service for your task. See here, for example:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot

Also, your symlink seems broken, it references itself.

Comment: There is already a `libvirtd` systemd service unit started during the boot. This should spawn all the virtual machines registered for autostart. Symlink should be correct- `/home/user/.config/libvirt/qemu/autostart/vm.xml` points to `/home/user/.config/libvirt/qemu/vm.xml`.